# Is it possible now to use microtype with opentype fonts?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype

LuaTeX has limited support for microtypograhpy now, and it can be invoked if only type1 fonts are used. But is it possible for `microtype` to work with opentype fonts loaded with `fontspec` now? I have searched the Internet for this, but most of the relevant information is outdated.

Comment: @Mico: OK, it works. I thought that microtype 2.5 was included in TeXLive 2012, since it had been out before 2011.

Comment: @Mico: Do you know how to install microtype 2.5 beta in miktex?

Comment: Installing in MiKTeX: First [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex), then [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You ask whether

> it [is] possible for `microtype` to work with OpenType fonts loaded with `fontspec`.

The short answer is yes. A longer answer would add that `microtype`'s functionality under LuaLaTeX isn't as complete as it is under pdfLaTeX. However, the limitations are *not* caused by the use of OpenType fonts.

The version of `microtype` that's currently distributed with TeXLive 2012 and MikTeX 2.9 is still version 2.4. However, a late-beta edition of version 2.5 of the `microtype` package, dated 2012-05-23, may be downloaded from http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=608. This version, when run under LuaLaTeX, still isn't as capable as when it's run under pdfLaTeX, but it comes a lot closer than if you stick with version 2.4.

You ask in a follow-up comment how version 2.5 of `microtype` might be installed manually under MikTeX. Do you have a "local" directory set up among the directories that are searched by MikTeX? (Bring up the "Settings" app of MikTeX to find out.) If not, do set up such a directory. Then, you could

- make sure that this local directory is topmost in the search order (so that the version of `microtype` to be installed by you in the local directory are seen before the "official" but now somewhat obsolete version that's still distributed with MikTeX 2.9);
- copy the files of microtype 2.5 beta to subdirectories of the local directory (such as `..\tex\latex\microtype` and `..\doc\microtype`); and
- update MikTeX's filename database; the particulars of this update process will depend on whether or not you installed MikTeX in ordinary mode or admin mode.

---

***Update***: Version 2.5a of the `microtype` package was released in May 2013.